# how i will execute two query with two different button

Tags: php

This is the html file

```
<label>Search:</label>
<input id="dontprint" type="text" style="" name="ssrch1">   

<input type="submit" Value="Search" id="dontprint"  class ="btn btn-success" name="btnssrch1">  

<label>Date From:</label>
<input type="text"id="jQueryDatePicker1" name="date1">

<label> To: </label>
<input type="text" id="jQueryDatePicker2" name="date2">

<input type="submit" Value="Search" id="dontprint" class="btn btn-success" name="btnssrch2">
```

In this function if you click btnssrch it will run the query but this is not the case after i click the btnssrch the query did not run. the second query is running but this is not what should i do ?

```
if(isset($_POST["btnssrch1"])) {        
    $cno1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST["ssrch1"]);   
    $p = mysqli_query($link,"select * from patient where CONCAT(PatientId,' ', FirstName,' ',MiddleName,' ',LastName) like '%$cno1%'");
}
```

In this functiton the query is executing.

```
 if(isset($_POST["btnssrch2"])) {
     $date1=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["date1"]);
     $date2=mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST["date2"]);
     $p = mysqli_query($link,"select * from patient where Date BETWEEN '" . $date1 . "' AND  '" . $date2 ."'");
 } else {
     $p=mysqli_query($link,"select * from patient");
 }

 while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($p)){
```

Comment: Are your two submit buttons named correctly?

Comment: can you put the html , be specific which button you are clicking and have you named them correctly?

Comment: i edit my post please see

Comment: Does your form have a method="post" attribute?

Comment: Then it's weird sis :) Attach var_dump($_POST) for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `<button>` tag instead of `<input type=submit>` by doing this when you click a particular button then this button will be set, now you can use isset function to check. The rest of the button will not be set untill you click on it. 
Like:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head> 
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ; ?>" method="post">
<button type="submit" name="button1"> firstButton </button>
<button type="submit" name="button2" >secondButton </button>
</form>
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    if (isset($_POST["button1"])) {
        echo "button 1 is set.<br>"; 
        var_dump(isset($_POST["button2"])); // var_dump will return the data type and the value.
    } elseif (isset($_POST["button2"])) {
        echo "button 2 is set.";
    } else {
        echo "no button is set.";
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

when you click first button is said button1 is set. when you click button2 it said button 2 is clicked.

or You can use two `<form>` element with two hidden inputs as other people suggesting u.

Comment: i use to form and i also use <button> but didint work for me